# How should I solve this DataFrame object is not callable error?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

```
ohe = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
ohe.fit_transform(file(['Areas of interest']))
```

I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As implied by the error message that you get, `file` is probably a pandas DataFrame.
Inside `fit_transform()` you have written:

```
file(['Areas of interest'])
```

while the correct would have been:

```
file['Areas of interest']
```

The extra parentheses in the first case cause the error you receive because `file` is not a function but a data frame.
You do not call data frames (using parentheses means that you are trying to pass an argument to a function), but you access their contents by indexing them (using square brackets `[]` with the name of a column as an argument).

Indexing can be done in many other ways. Refer to the [pandas user manual](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) for more details.